# How to revert changes made in local repo in Git (Not staged)

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am new to git. I have one project where I keep on making changes and I add, commit and then push to the remote repo from the local VS Code. Now I have made some changes in my local repo. So when I do git status I see changed files in "RED COLOUR". But I do not want these change. I want to see my local repo in sync with the last successful push.

**Expected Behaviour:**

So, when I do `git status` I should see message as "your local repo is in sync with master repo". Also, when I switch to Local VS code. I should get the prompt as "External source is modifying the files" And if I say YES. I get back to the last successful push.

[image]

P.S: I want all these changes to completely GO AWAY as it they were never made.

Attempt  made: I did `git checkout`. But after running it if I again type git status I again see these red files. I DO NOT Want to see these changes at all. Please help me here.

**EDIT Image :2 After GitCheckout**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `git checkout` command as shown:

```
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

Note that you need to include the names of the files in the `git checkout` command, or use `git checkout .` (note the trailing dot). A plain `git checkout` by itself won't do it.

Comment: Sir, can you kindly see another image I added. I ran command git checkout. But again when I ran git status. I see the red files again. Can you please see the image.

Comment: I would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: Ok. I will do that and I will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you so so much. It worked like charm.

Comment: All the changes are gone except some red files are still there under section "untraacked files" I want those files also to GO AWAY. How to acheive that?

Comment: For untracked files, use the `git clean -fd` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset HEAD --hard
git clean -fd
```